# keras training on big datasets seperately keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder, transfer-learning

I am working on a keras denoising neural network that denoise high Dimension x-ray images. The idea is to train on some datasets eg.1,2,3 and after having the weights, another datasets eg.4,5,6 will start with a new training with weights initialized from the previous training. Implementation-wise it works, however the weights resulted from the last rotation perform better only on the datasets that were used to train on in this rotation. Same goes for other rotation.

In other words, **weights resutlted from training on dataset: 4,5,6 doesn't give the good results on an image of dataset 1 as intended as the weights that were trained on datasets: 1,2,3. which shouldn't be what I intend to do**

The idea is that weights should be tweaked to work with all datasets effectively, as training on the whole dataset doesn't fit into memory.

*I tried other solutions such as creating custom generator that takes images from disk and do the training as batches which is very slow as it depends on factors like I/O operations happening on disk or the time complexity of processing functions happening inside the custom keras generator!*

Below is a code that shows what I am doing. I have 12 datasets, seperated into 4 checkpoints. data is loaded and training goes and saves final model to an array and next training takes the weights from the previous rotation and continues.

```
EPOCHES = 150
NUM_CHKPTS = 4
weights = []

for chk in range(1,NUM_CHKPTS+1):

    log_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'resnet_checkpts_' + str(EPOCHES) + "_tl2_chkpt" + str(chk))
    if not os.path.isdir(log_dir):
        os.makedirs(log_dir)
    else:
        print('Training log directory already exists @ {}.'.format(log_dir))
    tb_output = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

    print("Loading Data From CHKPT #" + str(chk))

    h5f = h5py.File('C:\\autoencoder\\datasets\\mix\\chk' + str(chk) + '.h5','r')
    org_patch = h5f['train_data'][:]
    noisy_patch = h5f['train_noisy'][:]
    h5f.close()

    input_patch, test_patch, noisy_patch, test_noisy_patch = train_test_split(org_patch, noisy_patch, train_size=0.8, shuffle=True)


    print("Reshaping")
    train_data = np.array([np.reshape(input_patch[i], (52, 52, 1)) for i in range(input_patch.shape[0])], dtype = np.float32)
    train_noisy_data = np.array([np.reshape(noisy_patch[i], (52, 52, 1)) for i in range(noisy_patch.shape[0])], dtype = np.float32)

    test_data = np.array([np.reshape(test_patch[i], (52, 52, 1)) for i in range(test_patch.shape[0])], dtype = np.float32)
    test_noisy_data = np.array([np.reshape(test_noisy_patch[i], (52, 52, 1)) for i in range(test_noisy_patch.shape[0])], dtype = np.float32)

    print('Number of training samples are:', train_data.shape[0])
    print('Number of test samples are:', test_data.shape[0])

    # IN = np.ones((len(XTRAINFILES), 52, 52, 1 ))

    if chk == 1:
        print("Generating the Model For The First Time..")
        autoencoder_model = model_autoencoder(train_noisy_data)
        print("Done!")
    else:
        autoencoder_model=load_model(weights[chk-2])


    checkpt_path = log_dir + r"\\cp-{epoch:04d}.ckpt"

    checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpt_path, verbose=0, save_weights_only=True, save_freq='epoch')


    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
    autoencoder_model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=optimizer) 

    autoencoder_model.fit(train_noisy_data, train_data,
                        batch_size=128,
                        epochs=EPOCHES, shuffle=True, verbose=1,
                        validation_data=(test_noisy_data, test_data),
                        callbacks=[tb_output, checkpoint_callback])

    weight_dir = log_dir+'\\model_resnet_new_OL' + str(EPOCHES) + 'epochs.h5'
    weights.append(weight_dir)
    autoencoder_model.save(weight_dir)  # Defined saved model name by number of epochs.
```

Tensorboard Graphs, Rotations are 1,2,3,4 from up down :
[image: First Rotation]

[image: Second Rotation]

[image: Third Rotation]

[image: Forth Rotation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model will forget previous dataset as you train on new dataset.

I read in reinforcement learning, when game are used to train Deep Reinforcement Learning (**DRL**), then you have to create memory replay, which collect data from different rounds of game, because each round of game has different data, then randomly some of that data is chosen to train model. that way **DRL** model can learn to play different rounds of game without forgetting previous rounds.

You can try to create a single dataset by taking some random samples from each dataset.

When you train model on new dataset that make sure data from all previous rotation are in current rotation.

Also in transfer learning, when you train model on new dataset, you have to freeze previous layers so that model don`t forget previous training. you are not using transfer learning but still when you start training on 2nd dataset your 1st dataset will slowly be removed from memory of weights.

you can try freezing initial layers of decoder so that they are not updated when extracting feature, assuming all of the dataset contain similar images, that way your model will not forget previous training as in transfer learning. but still when you train on new dataset previous will be forgotten.

Comment: i don't think so, the tensorboard graphs tells quite the opposite, I will add figures showing the loss

Comment: then maybe their is huge different between different dataset that you are using.

Comment: try creating 1 dataset for training, using data from all other datasets, specially different images of each dataset.

Comment: when you train alot, model will forget previous training, there is no point in training again and again on different datasets.

Comment: in transfer learning, when you train model on new dataset, you have to free previous layers so that model don`t forget previous training. you are not using transfer learning but still when you start training on 2nd dataset your 1st dataset will slowly be removed from memory of weights.

Comment: can you explain on what basis you freeze some layers and leave others?. I have seen implementations of this but non explained or made sense

Comment: normally initial layer extract feature, while the last layers make decision based on features from initial layers. so you have to freeze initial layers. this will make model extract feature from images without updating weights when training on new data.

Comment: in your case try freezing initial layer of encoder and final layers of decoder. since middle layers have the important data in auto encoder.

Comment: or you can try freezing just some initial layers of encoder. keep training decoder. it might work since you only have X-Rays images

Comment: this technique only work on similar images, if you need totally different images then they require new feature extraction layer, which are the initial layer.

Comment: in each rotation, should more layers be frozen? So in rotation 1 no layers will be frozen, second rotation, initial layers will be frozen and others will fine tune accordingly. what happen in the third rotation and forth?

Comment: you only have to freeze initial layer once they are trained on one dataset. so only after 1st rotation you need to freeze the layers. that will make feature extraction stable. but to make it work on different dataset you have to combine data from all dataset and train together. because after training on 2nd dataset your 1st dataset will be forgotten.

Comment: i read in reinforcement learning, when game are used to train Deep Reinforcement Learning(DRL), then you have to create memory replay, which collect data from different rounds of game, because each round of game has different data, then randomly some of that data is chosen to train model. that way DRL model can learn to play different rounds of game without forgetting previous rounds

Comment: makes sense, so the solution would be to freeze initial layers plus including some data from rotation n into rotation n+1, n+2, ...etc. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, make sure data from all previous rotation are in current rotation.

Comment: thanks alot, would be good if you edited the answer and summarized this to accept your answer ;)